# Async call to ReadFile function returns 6 error code

Tags: c++, asynchronous, readfile

I wrote the c++ code below in order to read a file asynchronously:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
HANDLE hFile;
DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
BYTE *buf = (BYTE*)malloc(BUF_SIZE*sizeof(BYTE));
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
overlapped.Offset = overlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;  

hFile = CreateFile("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\FOO.cpp",
                  GENERIC_READ,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                  NULL);



 if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        printf("invalid hfile\n");

   int i;   
   i= ReadFile(hFile,
                 &buf,
                 BUF_SIZE,
                 &NumberOfBytesRead,
                 &overlapped);

  if(!i && GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
         printf ("ReadFile failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
   else
   {  
     WaitForSingleObject(&(overlapped.hEvent), 0);
     printf("here it is %d",NumberOfBytesRead );
   }

   CloseHandle(hFile);
```

But the return value from ReadFile is 0, and the last error equals to 6.
Does anyone have any idea **why**? and what does 6 error code say?

Thanks!.

Comment: Just add proper initialization: `OVERLAPPED overlapped = {};`.

Comment: Also, you probably want to wait `INFINITE` time, not 0. Also, `NumberOfBytesRead` will not be updated after the wait, you must call `GetOverlappedResult` to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your problem is with OVERLAPPED structure, which you don't initialize properly.
See: "Any unused members of this structure should always be initialized to zero before the structure is used in a function call. Otherwise, the function may fail and return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER." in remarks here: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use memset to clear all of it.

Comment: Indeed, "invalid handle" is probably referring to `overlapped.hEvent`.

Comment: and..? what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Something like this: memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped)) instead of your overlapped.Offset = overlapped.OffsetHigh = 0; line.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 6 means invalid handle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Which seems odd since you check for invalid handle value. Not sure if this helped you but I might try opening the file synchronously first.